# Fork two processes and kill the second when the first is done

Tags: bash, kill

I want to create a bash script that will launch two processes and kill the second process when the first is done.  Here's an example:

```
#fork first process
producer&

#fork second process
consumer&

#wait for producer to finish
...

#kill the consumer
...
```

I have a feeling this can get ugly but has a very simple solution.  Please help me fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
foo & pid_foo=$!
bar & pid_bar=$!

wait $pid_foo
kill $pid_bar
```

But perhaps you could just run `foo | bar` (if that happens to work with stdin/stdout handling).

Comment: The pipe is clever but perhaps you don't want the stdin/stdout consequences

Comment: you don't need the pids, you can use %1, %2

Comment: @Patrick: If the processes are actually just numbered, that might make sense. In the general case, though, it makes more sense to name the variables `pid_foo` and `pid_bar`, and that is more clear when reading the code than `%1` and `%2`. However, thanks for mentioning that this possibility exists (at least in bash).

Comment: No need for intermediate variables:
You can name your processes: kill %foo

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash 

#enable job control in script
set -m

producer &

consumer &

fg %1

kill %2
```